# R converstion from long to wide

Tags: r, bar-chart, transformation

I'm pretty new to R and need the community's help regarding my problem.

I have this set of data that i'm planning to stacked bar plot.

```
date        id  column1 column2     
2015-09-01  206 96301   91807    
2015-09-02  206 87543   88082    
2015-09-03  206 87636   89064   
2015-09-04  206 95445   93241    
2015-09-05  206 93510   93640   
2015-09-06  206 153797  106226
```

The way i understand it, i need to convert this data frame to a wide format.
I've tried to reshape it but it doesn't seem to go reshape the way i need it.

Is it possible if i can reshape it to this format:

```
date id 2015-09-01  2015-09-02  2015-09-03  2015-09-04  2015-09-05  2015-09-06
column1 96301   87543   87636   95445   2156-01-07  153797  
column2 91807   88082   89064   93241   93640   106226
```

Comment: You need to spend more time formatting this. For example use Ctrl-k to mark sections as code.

Comment: You can use the transform function `t()`

Comment: Please post your code that we could see the issue and then we could help better. Thank you.

Comment: Who told you that you need it in a wide format? How exactly you want your bar plot to look like with the provided data set?

Comment: Sorry still haven't got used to posting, will do better next time.

Comment: I'm planning to do a stacked barplot of column1 and column2 per date. Is there an easier way for me to do it? Thanks a lot everyone!

Comment: @dstudio if my answer helped you out, please mark it as correct answer :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the function `t()` to transform your data.

```
> A <- matrix(c("2015-09-01","2015-09-02","2015-09-03","2015-09-04","2015-09-05","2015-09-06"), ncol = 6)
> B <- matrix(c(96301,87543,87636,95445,93510,153797), ncol = 6)
> C <- matrix(c(91807,88082,89064,93241,93640,106226), ncol = 6)
> AB <- rbind.fill.matrix(A,B, C)
> AB <- t(AB)
> colnames(AB) <- c("Col1", "Col2", "Farm")
> 
> AB
  Col1         Col2     Farm    
1 "2015-09-01" "96301"  "91807" 
2 "2015-09-02" "87543"  "88082" 
3 "2015-09-03" "87636"  "89064" 
4 "2015-09-04" "95445"  "93241" 
5 "2015-09-05" "93510"  "93640" 
6 "2015-09-06" "153797" "106226"
```

Now you can use the t() function.

```
> t(AB)
     1            2            3            4            5            6           
Col1 "2015-09-01" "2015-09-02" "2015-09-03" "2015-09-04" "2015-09-05" "2015-09-06"
Col2 "96301"      "87543"      "87636"      "95445"      "93510"      "153797"    
Farm "91807"      "88082"      "89064"      "93241"      "93640"      "106226"    
>
```

---

For creating a stacked bar chart I'd recommend taking a look at [this page](http://www.harding.edu/fmccown/r/#barcharts) 
 It shows in detail how to create several different (bar) charts

---

Hope this helped you!